# How to Force Matlab to Display Node Labels For Large Graph

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I have a Matlab script which creates a graph, named `mygraph` based upon an edge list of pairs of character vectors. Running `mygraph.Nodes` returns a `134x1` table containing all of my vertex names, so I know that they are attached to my graph. However, when I plot the graph (using the standard `plot` function), the vertices are all unlabeled. I suspect, because according to [Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.labelnode.html) it should automatically display node labels, that this is a function of the large number of vertices which I am trying to plot. Is this assessment correct? If so, how can I fix this problem?
[Here](https://github.com/nosyarg/OilNetwork/blob/master/oilgraph.mat) and [here](https://github.com/nosyarg/OilNetwork/blob/master/problemexample.m) are the files necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post!

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip, I will do that

Comment: Is there an easy way to include my data in an edit? It is quite a large amount, and I doubt that my problem will reproduce with less.

Comment: You could generate random data if that will allow to reproduce the problem. If you use Matlab's builtin functions (such as `rand` or `randn` and others) to generate the data anyone can reproduce it without needing your actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment is correct; the node labels aren't appearing because your graph has more than 100 nodes. You can manually assign them if you have a cellstr of the node names though.  An example:

```
>> A = delsq(numgrid('L',14));
>> G = graph(A,'OmitSelfLoops');
>> p = plot(G);
>> p.NodeLabel = arrayfun(@num2str, 1:108, 'UniformOutput', false);
```